# Passwordless access to raspberry pi via ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I can't setup passwordless access to Raspberry Pi. I am using similar instructions like this [one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md). But it still asks for password when I 
ssh to my raspberry. I made this with other servers and everything worked ok, but not with my raspberry (both of them).

Thanks to Jakuje, become a little bit clearer:

successful debug log:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:XPQA6tgcRCam/L18YP4ccPwsOsGtO65ippi7kua4mTM
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:XPQA6tgcRCam/L18YP4ccPwsOsGtO65ippi7kua4mTM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

fail log:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Why it ignores `id_rsa` key and asks for `id_dsa` ???

Comment: What steps did you made to make it working? How does the debug log look like? Without either of that, this is not possible to answer.

Comment: Link to instructions is in the post. I perform them and PI still asks for password. What log do you need - which commands should I execute or where it is located? I will give you - no problems

Comment: `ssh -vvv raspberry-ip`

Comment: Please see updated post

Comment: Because the `id_rsa` key is rejected by the server for some reason. You can turn on the debug information in the server too to get more information why does it reject the key.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to turn on debug on server?

Comment: Put `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config`, restart `sshd` service, try to connect again and have a look into the log/journal.

Comment: Thanks! Problem was in Bad Ownership or Modes for Directory http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/
You could answer my question if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tmp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

says that the key was tried but not accepted by server. There will be a problem in server configuration/permissions. Running the server in debug mode identifies where the problem is. The owners and permissions on home directory, `.ssh` directory should be the following:

```
chmod g-w /home/your_user
chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Yes, this was my case http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/